# How can I query the length of my array with firestore?

Tags: react-native, google-cloud-firestore

this is my object

```
readUserIDS:[
    0: ID1
    1:ID2
]
```

or

```
readUserIDS:[
    0: ID1
]
```

I wanna render just the array with 1 ID but I don't know how to query my array with firestore. Basically, I wanna find just the array.length with one ID

```
  const notification = () => {
    channelsRef
      .where('channelID', '==', item.id)
      .get()
      .then((querySnapshot) => {
        querySnapshot.forEach((doc) => {
          doc.ref
            .collection('thread')
            .where('senderID', '==', item.participants[0].id)
            .where('readUserIDs.2', '>', '')
            .get()
            .then((querySnapshot) => {
              console.log('size', querySnapshot.size);
              querySnapshot.forEach((thread) => {
                let data = querySnapshot.size;
                console.log('data', data);
              });
            });
        });
      });
  };
```

Answer (score 2):

Edit in April 25 2023:

Now we can use the `.count()` function. Check documentation in https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/aggregation-queries.

This is quite useful because it avoids retrieving all the collection items from the DB. Cheaper and faster.

---

Old answer:

```js
  const notification = () => {
    channelsRef
      .where('channelID', '==', item.id)
      .get()
      .then((querySnapshot) => {
        querySnapshot.forEach((doc) => {
          doc.ref
            .collection('thread')
            .where('senderID', '==', item.participants[0].id)
            .where('readUserIDs.2', '>', '')
            .get()
            .then((querySnapshot) => {
              return querySnapshot.size;
            });
        });
      });
  };
```

Comment: @Xwingoga06 Could you please confirm if the answer was helpful? if it is could you upvote or accept the answer? It will really help the community.